# Like/dislike system using AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently working on my first RoR project. For now i'd like to make integrate a like/dislike system into my application. I have some code, but it works just only when the page is reloaded. My goal is to make the ability to like/dislike a post without reloading the page(using Ajax, not the built-in one). So, here's my code, what is wrong here ?

My controller

```
def like
    @post=Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.increment!(:like)
    render :nothing => true, :status => 200
  end

  def dislike
    @post=Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.increment!(:dislike)
    render :nothing => true, :status => 200
  end
```

my view

```
<table>
  <% if @post.count!=0 %>
    <% @post.each do |p| %>
      <%if !p.text.nil?%>
        <tr data-post_id="<%= p.id %>">
       <td><b class="margin"><h4><%=p.text%></b></h4></td>
       <td>by <%= link_to p.user.username, profile_dashboard_path(p.user) %>&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
       <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up likeAction"><%=  p.like %> </td>
       <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down dislikeAction"><%= p.dislike %> </td>
      <%end%>
    <% end %>
  <%else%>
    There's no posts yet, but you can add <%=link_to "one", create_a_post_dashboard_path(current_user)%>
  <%end%>
</table>
```

my js file, which is located in app/assets/javascripts/dashboard.js, so i dont have any js file with the name like.js.erb or dislike.js.erb(i'm not sure if i need them)

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".likeAction").click(function(){
    var current_post_tr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/' + $(current_post_tr).attr('data-post_id') +'/like',
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(){
          $(".likeAction").hide().fadeIn();
          location.reload();
        }
     });
  });

  $(".dislikeAction").click(function(){
    var current_post_tr = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/' + $(current_post_tr).attr('data-post_id') +'/dislike',
        type: 'PUT',
        success: function(){
          $(".dislikeAction").hide().fadeIn();
          location.reload();
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You are reloading the page after ajax success. Have you tried changing the text of $('. dislikeAction') or $('. likeAction') by subtracting/adding 1 after success?

Comment: no, beceause i'm not so strong in jQuery. could you give me an example ?

Comment: `var dislikes = $(".dislikeAction").text();`
`$(".dislikeAction").text(parseInt(dislikes)+1)`

Comment: If you mean something like this   jQuery(function($) {
  $(".likeAction").click(function(){
    var likes = $(".likeAction").text();
    $.ajax({
       $(".likeAction").text(parseInt(likes)+1);
        });
  });
}); then it doesn't work

Comment: No, I did not mean that. Try to increase the "likes" and "dislikes" when your ajax post is successful. 
        `success: function(){`
          `$(".dislikeAction").hide().fadeIn();`
          `var dislikes = $(".dislikeAction").text();  `    `$(".dislikeAction").text(parseInt(dislikes)+1) // similarly for likes`
        `}`

Comment: Thank you very much ! it works. But there's one more error. When i click my like/dislike more than one time it incremets by one, but shows incredibly big nubmers, do you know why ?

Comment: Can you give me example as what the number was before click and what happens after click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: function(){ 
    $(".dislikeAction").hide().fadeIn(); 
    var dislikes = parseInt($(".dislikeAction").text());  
    $(".dislikeAction").text(dislikes+1) // similarly for likes 
}
```

Comment: i resolved it this way : if($('.likeAction').data('clicked')){ 
      } ,  thanks for your help, i appreciate it